# How to enable data compression in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, compression, zlib

In MongoDB, WiredTiger provides the Zlib compression option.

To enable the Zlib compression option, I created a collection using the following code.

```
db.createCollection( "questions", { storageEngine: {
                   wiredTiger: { configString: "blockCompressor=zlib" }}})
```

I ran some simple tests to measure compression performance and used following data sets storing strings

```
{
'_id': <ObjectID>,
'question_id': <Five character string>,
'question': <My question>
}
```

I created another one collection with any compression option using the following code.

```
db.createCollection( "questions")
```

Measured the data size using following comment

```
db.stats(1024*1024).dataSize + db.stats(1024*1024).indexSize
```

But I can't able to see the compression difference between these two collections. I referred the following links to achieve my process.

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/new-compression-options-mongodb-30

https://scalegrid.io/blog/enabling-data-compression-in-mongodb-3-0/

Answer (score 7):

Don't use `dataSize` for this comparison since it's the uncompressed size. Use `storageSize` instead.

Using MongoDB 4.2.2 for example:

```
// create collections
> db.createCollection('snappy')
> db.createCollection('zlib', {storageEngine: {wiredTiger: {configString: 'block_compressor=zlib'}}})

// insert a compressible document into both collections
> doc = {_id:0, text:<a paragraph of text>}
> db.snappy.insert(doc)
> db.zlib.insert(doc)

// storage size comparison
> db.snappy.stats().storageSize
20480
> db.zlib.stats().storageSize
4096

// data size comparison
> db.snappy.dataSize()
697
> db.zlib.dataSize()
697
```

So the storage size of zlib is much smaller than default (snappy), but data size are the same between them.

**Note**: If you're still using it, MongoDB 3.0 is very much outdated and not supported anymore since [February 2018](https://www.mongodb.com/support-policy). Please use a more recent version (latest as of Jan 2020 is 4.2.2).

Comment: The storageSize returns: The total amount of storage in bytes allocated to this collection for document storage.

ref: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.storageSize/

For size comparison we must use ***db.collection.totalSize()***

This returns: **The total size in bytes of the data in the collection plus the size of every index on the collection.**

Ref: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.totalSize/#db.collection.totalsize--

Answer (score 0):

**db.createCollection( "questions", { storageEngine: {
wiredTiger: { configString: "blockCompressor=zlib" }}})**

**ERROR** -- throws invalid argument

use instead

**db.createCollection( "email", { storageEngine: {wiredTiger: { configString: "block_compressor=zlib" }}})**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).