# Does Snappy/Zlib compressions in mongo only reduced the bandwidth or the document size saved in DB

Tags: mongodb, compression, zlib, snappy

Recently for one of the projects, we require compressions for MongoDB documents, Found out there are multiple compressions algo like snappy, zlib and etc.
Most of the articles on these only talked about network compressions and reduced bandwidth usage but didn't mention the space saved due to compression.
My question is do these compressions save the disk space too or decompress the data before storing it in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

The compression that you configure in the mongoclient is responsible only for network traffic between client and server. To configure how the data should be stored on the server side, you should use `storage engine`, see [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/wiredtiger/#compression). Also you can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59610238/how-to-enable-data-compression-in-mongodb).